# How to Parse an Array in a JSON object with npm dlv (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, npm, get

I am getting a response from a GET request. I need to parse it and get the value for the key **baseEntityCode** which would be **CPY_COMPANY1**. I am using npm dlv https://www.npmjs.com/package/dlv as I can use the dot-notated path. The JSON has an array and I still haven't found a way to get the key path after I used the example given by npm docs as guidance,

```
//use string dot notation for keys
delve(obj, 'a.b.c') === 1;

//or use an array key
delve(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c']) === 1;
```

Here is the JSON response (I've taken out some key values that may be confidential to our company).

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "baseEntityAttributes": [
        {
          "baseEntityCode": "CPY_COMPANY1",
          "attributeCode": "PRI_ABN",
          "readonly": false,
          "index": 0,
          "created": "2020-02-06T23:21:09.414",
          "valueString": "51824753556",
          "weight": 1.0,
          "inferred": false,
          "privacyFlag": false
        },
        {
          "baseEntityCode": "CPY_COMPANY1",
          "attributeCode": "PRI_ADDRESS_ADDRESS1",
          "readonly": false,
          "index": 0,
          "created": "2020-02-06T23:17:43.126",
          "valueString": "removed",
          "weight": 1.0,
          "inferred": false,
          "privacyFlag": false
        },
        {
          "baseEntityCode": "CPY_COMPANY1",
          "attributeCode": "PRI_CPY_NAME",
          "readonly": false,
          "index": 0,
          "created": "removed",
          "valueString": "removed",
          "weight": 1.0,
          "inferred": false,
          "privacyFlag": false
        },
        {
          "baseEntityCode": "CPY_COMPANY1",
          "attributeCode": "PRI_ADDRESS_POSTCODE",
          "readonly": false,
          "index": 0,
          "created": "removed",
          "valueString": "removed",
          "weight": 1.0,
          "inferred": false,
          "privacyFlag": false
        },
        {
          "baseEntityCode": "CPY_COMPANY1",
          "attributeCode": "PRI_ADDRESS_FULL",
          "readonly": false,
          "index": 0,
          "created": "2020-02-06T23:21:01.87",
          "valueString": "removed",
          "weight": 1.0,
          "inferred": false,
          "privacyFlag": false
        },
        {
          "baseEntityCode": "CPY_COMPANY1",
          "attributeCode": "PRI_ADDRESS_COUNTRY",
          "readonly": false,
          "index": 0,
          "created": "removed",
          "valueString": "removed",
          "weight": 1.0,
          "inferred": false,
          "privacyFlag": false
        },
        {
          "baseEntityCode": "CPY_COMPANY1",
          "attributeCode": "PRI_ADDRESS_CITY",
          "readonly": false,
          "index": 0,
          "created": "2020-02-06T23:18:07.324",
          "valueString": "removed",
          "weight": 1.0,
          "inferred": false,
          "privacyFlag": false
        },
        {
          "baseEntityCode": "CPY_COMPANY1",
          "attributeCode": "PRI_ADDRESS_STATE",
          "readonly": false,
          "index": 0,
          "created": "removed",
          "valueString": "removed",
          "weight": 1.0,
          "inferred": false,
          "privacyFlag": false
        }
      ],
      "links": [],
      "questions": [],
      "code": "CPY_COMPANY1",
      "index": 0,
      "created": "removed",
      "id": removed,
      "name": "removed",
      "realm": "removed"
    }
  ],
  "parentCode": "SBE_TEST2",
  "total": 1,
  "returnCount": 1,
  "data_type": "BaseEntity",
  "delete": false,
  "replace": false,
  "msg_type": "DATA_MSG",
  "option": "EXEC"
}
```

You can use Runkit https://npm.runkit.com/dlv to test your code.

Please let me know if the question is not clear and you need more clarity. Thanks!

Comment: `delve(obj, 'items.0.code')` or `delve(obj, 'items.0.baseEntityAttributes.0.baseEntityCode')` will give you the same output. An Array is an Object. It only has the specificity of only having numeric enumerable keys (this excludes other keys like `.length`, `.map`, `.forEach`... which Arrays do have)

Comment: @blex I would suggest you to make it an answer rather than a comment [check below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like entering the array index number just as you would a key is the way to go. For example

```
delve(response, 'items.0.baseEntityAttributes.0.baseEntityCode')
```

gives

```
CPY_COMPANY1
```

which is

```
{
   "items": [
        {
          "baseEntityAttributes": [
            {
              "baseEntityCode": "CPY_COMPANY1", // <--- This value
              "attributeCode": "PRI_ABN",
              "readonly": false,
              "index": 0,
              "created": "2020-02-06T23:21:09.414",
              "valueString": "51824753556",
              "weight": 1.0,
              "inferred": false,
              "privacyFlag": false
            }, ...
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @blex already gave the same exact answer in the comment to the question, the points should go to him